# Assigning unique_ptr vector to vector c++

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I'm currently trying to incorporate dynamic footstep audio into my game. Heres some code for now:

```
class MyClass
{
    vector< unique_ptr <Sound> > footstep_a;
    vector< unique_ptr <Sound> > footstep_b;
    vector< unique_ptr <Sound> > footstep_c;
    vector< Sound > currentfootsteps;
}
```

So basically what I want to do is assign one of the footstep_ vectors to currentfootsteps so that I can then have:

```
if( walkingarea == a )
    currentfootsteps = a;
else ......
```

I've tried doing the following, but it just throws up a million errors about vectors and such:

```
if ( walkingarea == a )
    currentfootsteps.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < footstep_a.size(); i++)
        currentfootsteps.push_back( footstep_a[i] );
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You're pushing back a `std::unique_ptr<>` to a vector of `Sound` objects. That's why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but assuming the `Sound` class is copyable, this will compile:

```
currentfootsteps.clear();
for(auto const& up : footstep_a) {
    currentfootsteps.push_back(*up);
}
```

Note that you're making a copy of each element in `footstep_a` and adding it to `currentfootsteps`.

If `Sound` is move-only, or you want to avoid copies, use this instead:

```
currentfootsteps.clear();
for(auto&& up : footstep_a) {
    currentfootsteps.push_back(std::move(*up));
}
```

But it also seems you should be able to avoid all this by making `currentfootsteps` a pointer, and simply pointing to one of the `vector`s depending on whatever condition is satisfied.

```
vector< unique_ptr <Sound> > *currentfootsteps = nullptr;

if ( walkingarea == a ) {
  currentfootsteps = &footstep_a;
} else if ...
```

Comment: Excellent thanks. Completely didn't think about using your last suggestion lmao. How stupid can you get haha

Answer (score 1):

As the name sugguested, unique_ptr should be moved rather than be copied in:

> ```
> currentfootsteps.push_back( footstep_a[i] );
> ```

You may try to get the raw pointer with `.get()` then put it into currentfootsteps.
At the mean time you need to ensure the lifetime of the `Sound` object is long enough.

Because from my understanding, `currentfootsteps` only hold the reference to those `Sound` object, while `footstep_a`, `footstep_b`, `footstep_c` actually own them.